# Extract snippet out of HTML with Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, text-processing, textile, code-snippets

I need to show the first 100 characters of an HTML text, which means, I have to pick the first 100 characters that are *not* tags and then close any open tags leaving a balanced HTML. Is there any library that can do it? Or is there any trivial way to do it that I am missing?

The text is originally written in Textile which can and does contain HTML, so I figured I am better off turning it to fully HTML first and then processing, but if something can do it at the Textile level, I'm happy too.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would get the first 100 chars of text. You may need to modify according to your needs

```
require 'nokogiri'

def get_first_100_chars
 doc = Nokogiri::Slop(open 'html_file.html')
 text = doc.html.body.text
 return text[0..99]
end
```

Not sure about balancing the html. Will post if I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)

Comment: I'm already familiar with Nokogiri, but I need more than just a parser to achieve this. Maybe Nokogiri can do it, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. So in this case - you could explain why/how nokogiri is useful for the poster.

Comment: You are right of course. But are you guys bots? I find it suspicious how 2 people suddenly on the same day add a comment to a 2 year old post, and the first sentence is exactly the same.